# CListCtrl selection

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm trying to do something that I think is simple but I can't seem to make it work!

I have a `CListCtrl` and I want to select the last element in the list if the user clicks in the view empty space. I can do that just by calling `Select(lastElementInList)`, but the element that was previously selected and that is now unselected still has a "bounding rectangle" around it.

The code that Implements this is as follows:

```
    int nSel = GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
    if (nSel != -1)
        SetItemState(nSel, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);

    Select(lastElementInList);
```

Any hints? What am I missing?

Comment: By "bounding rectangle", do you mean a dotted outline around the item? That's the focus indicator, which is supposed to appear since you clicked in the list in the first place. It's a harmless and useful indicator, maybe you could leave it as it is?

Comment: That's exactly what it is. Need to get my nomenclature right! That is an option. But for all intents and purposes what I am trying to replicate is the same thing that happens when I click other item on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *"bounding rectangle"* you see indicates that the element currently is *"focused"*, ie. in a state where a user interaction, such as pressing the down and up arrows, would start off from this point.

---

**Change focused element**

To move *focus* to your newly selected element you'll have to use [`SetItemState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t97k8h9.aspx) together with `LVIS_FOCUSED`, as in the below example:

```
if (nSel != -1)
    SetItemState (nSel, ~LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_FOCUSED);          // (1)

SetItemState (lastElementInList, LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_FOCUSED);  // (2)
```

```
// (1) -> Remove focus from `nSel`
// (2) -> Add focus to `lastElementInList`
```

Comment: Great! I knew it had to be something simple. The problem of not working with something for a couple of years now ;) Thanks!